# Regex to get conten between two single quote in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Can you show me the way to get content `my device` and `image` in this string by ruby

```
if(my_device=='galaxytab210') { image = 'http:image.com'
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = %q|if(my_device=='galaxytab210') { image = 'http:image.com'|
my_device, image = str.scan(/'([^']+)'/).flatten
```

Comment: @DoThanhTung Glad to see it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, benchmarking some code reveals some *very* minor efficiencies in using a lookaround instead of the capture group and Array#flatten.

EDIT NOTE: Fixed the code as Arie pointed out and the capture + flatten method appears to be more efficient. This might be due to the speed of Array operations, which are analogous to the C code (and therefore more simply modeled) they are written in in MRI ruby.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'benchmark'

str = "if(my_device=='galaxytab210') { image = 'http:image.com'"

def with_lookaround(str)
  str.scan(/(?<=')[^'\s]+(?=')/)
end

def with_flatten(str)
  str.scan(/'([^']+)'/).flatten
end

repetitions = 1_000_000

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report('with lookaround') { repetitions.times { with_lookaround(str) } }
  bm.report('with array flatten') { repetitions.times { with_flatten(str) } }
end

__END__

           user     system      total        real
with lookaround  5.140000   0.020000   5.160000 (  5.181926)
with array flatten  4.950000   0.020000   4.970000 (  5.041639)

       user     system      total        real
with lookaround  5.200000   0.020000   5.220000 (  5.281581)
with array flatten  4.680000   0.020000   4.700000 (  4.755978)
```

Comment: I think that's the expected result. The capture group and flatten approach has the overhead of capture the matched content and then extract the contents of inner array to form the result array.

Comment: BTW, your `repetitions` doesn't work as expected. I think you mean `repetitions.times { with_lookaround(str) }`

Comment: The lookarounds come with their own overhead, but it seems to be somewhat optimized. Thanks for spotting the bug in my code.